# Create Table Through JOIN SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, syntax-error, left-join

I need to create a new table in my database through a left join statement of two tables from different schemas.  Here is my code below:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE
  FROM SCHEMA_1.TABLE_A X
  LEFT JOIN SCHEMA_2.TABLE_B Y
     ON X.NAME = Y.NAME 
        AND X.NUMBER = Y.NUMBER
```

I'm getting a SQL error:

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
> 00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"

Comment: You are missing a `select`.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to create a table rather than creating a view?  It would seem more likely that you'd want to create a view that joins the two tables so that you can query the view and get up-to-date data rather than having a stale copy of the data.

Comment: Im new to using views so if I understand correctly a view is more dynamic and updates as the two parent tables update?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `as select` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE
AS ( -- This was missing
    SELECT    * -- So was this
    FROM      SCHEMA_1.TABLE_A X
    LEFT JOIN SCHEMA_2.TABLE_B Y ON X.NAME = Y.NAME AND
                                    X.NUMBER = Y.NUMBER
   )
```

Comment: `SELECT *` won't work as the two tables share fields with the same name.

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `NUMBER`as a column name it is a oracle keyword.

Coming to the query, if the only common columns in the two tables are `NAME`,`NUMBER` then you can try this

```
 CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE
 AS (
SELECT    * 
FROM      SCHEMA_1.TABLE_A X
LEFT JOIN SCHEMA_2.TABLE_B Y Using(NAME,NUMBER)
)
```

Comment: Nitpicking: the parentheses around the select are useless

Comment: Thanks.  Appreciate the help.